# Bootstrap: Form display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I like bootstrap, but when it comes to forms it's really inconvenient. I made myself classes for a comment box that should flowing on the top and (ideally push other elements below on smartphone screens). **I couldn't figure out how to have the name and surname on the same line**. I've made following demo:

```css
.comment-box-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 812px;
  right: 40px;
  z-index: 1001;
  width: 500px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.comment-box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #DCE0E0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.comment-box-header {
  background-color: rgba(38, 173, 228, 0.9);
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
/* Remove rounded borders on input fields */

.form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
}
/* Disable the ability to resize textareas */

textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="comment-box-container">
  <div class="comment-box-header">
    Kontakt
  </div>
  <div class="comment-box">
    <form role="form" class="forminline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Vorname" id="surname">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="telephone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefon" id="telephone">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Nachricht" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Interesse bekunden</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to display surname and name on the same line and the button in the center over the whole width. Possible? (P.S. What kind of buttons is Stack Overflow using below?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9tjhmzo5/1)

1. You need to add grid classes to the first two inputs. `col-xs-6`
   will divide the inputs by giving them a width of `50%` and align
   them in a line. Make sure you have wrapped the two inputs inside a
   `row` so that next inputs are aligned as it is, without disturbing
   the flow.
2. `text-center` class to the `commentbox` class will align the button
   to center.
3. To reduce the space between the two input box, you will need to override the padding-left to 0. Note that I am targeting the second input so that only the spacing is effected.

   ```
   .comment-box .form-group.col-xs-6:nth-child(2) {
     padding-left: 0;
   }
   ```
4. To give a custom color to the button, you will again need to override the bootstrap classes.

   ```
   .comment-box .btn {
      background-color: lightgray;
   }
   ```

```css
.comment-box-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 40px;
  z-index: 1001;
  width: 500px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.comment-box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #DCE0E0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.comment-box-header {
  background-color: rgba(38, 173, 228, 0.9);
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
/* Remove rounded borders on input fields */

.form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
}
/* Disable the ability to resize textareas */

textarea {
  resize: none;
}

.comment-box .form-group.col-xs-6:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.comment-box .btn {
   background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="comment-box-container">
  <div class="comment-box-header">
    Kontakt
  </div>
  <div class="comment-box text-center">
    <form role="form" class="forminline">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
          <input type="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Vorname" id="surname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
          <input type="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="telephone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefon" id="telephone">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Nachricht" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Interesse bekunden</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Manoj. Can one make the space between above two name boxes a bit smaller? And can you give the button an own (non-bootstrap) color?

Comment: No problem. I just edited the post for your new questions :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a hover-attribute for mouseover-coloring on this button?

Comment: You can open a new question for your queries. My answer will not be relevant to your question content if I answer it here.